# How to override odoo im_chat.js file?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, livechat

I want to customize code in im_chat.js -> im_chat.ConversationManager with my own javascript file, not changing any code from im_chat.js file.

Can anyone tell me good practice on how to do this?

Here are the functions i want to customize:

- List item
- window_title_change
- apply_session
- activate_session
- delete_session
- received_message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method:

```
openerp.your_module = function(instance) {
im_chat.ConversationManager.include({
    window_title_change : function(){
        //Your code
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Hi @KbiR this is correct and working, but what about the "u=instance", what is that for?